# Rails 4 - JQuery Datepicker not displaying in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery-UI to display the datepicker on a simple rails form. In my local development environment it works as expected, but when I deploy to the production environment it will not display.

Gem File includes:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
em 'jquery-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
```

My application.js

```
//= require jsapi
//= require chartkick
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require holder
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require dataTables.bootstrap
//= require highcharts.js
//= require_tree .
```

My application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "partials/*";
@import "customer/*";
@import "jquery-ui/datepicker";
```

The form contains:

```
<div class="row">
<label class="control-label col-xs-3">Start Date :</label>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<%= f.input :start_date, :as => :datepicker, :label => false %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"><label class="control-label col-xs-3">End Date :</label>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<%= f.input :complete_date, :as => :datepicker, :label => false %>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a dates.js.coffee file as follows:

```
$ ->
  $("input.datepicker").each (i) ->
    $(this).datepicker
      altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
      altField: $(this).next()
```

Any help would be fantastic...

Comment: Do you get any errors about js in console on your browser?

Comment: The js console does show some errors
application-0738d2f53fa641359e275e1f993b1736.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Comment: First one sounds like your error, If you get an error before it gets to your datepicker code then it won't load it.  From the error (purely guessing) it sounds like you might need to put something in to load when the dom is ready.  The others sound like you've not precompiled the assets since uploading them.  If you click on the error for js it should should you the line the errors on.  If you wouldn't mind can you post that bit of js please.

Comment: Comes up as line 15, column 374
module.exports=function(t){t.initConfig({pkg:t.file.readJSON("package.json"),banner:'/*\n\n<%= pkg.name %> - <%= pkg.version %> - <%= pkg.summary %>\n(c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %> / <%= pkg.author.url %>\n\nProvided under the <%= pkg.license.type %> License: <%= pkg.license.url %>\nCommercial use requires attribution.\n\n*/\n',jshint:{options:{jshintrc:".jshintrc"},gruntfile:{src:"Gruntfile.js"},src:{src:["holder.js"]}},uglify:{options:{banner:"<%= banner %>"},dist:{src:"holder.js",dest:"holder.min.js"}}})

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to japed for pointing me in the right direction. I was inadvertently loading a JS file (gruntfile.js) via the asset pipeline that was not loading correctly and causing the rest of the JS to not load. I removed this file and all is working as expected.